# How to fire iOS10 LocalNotification repeatedly after delay?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, ios10

I noticed repeatInterval in UILocalNotification is gone on iOS10. 
How to fire UNUserNotification repeatedly after delay?

for example notify user every 30second after 1 hour later.

Thanks.

(I'm not asking about old UILocalNotification)

Comment: oh sorry wrong post

Comment: I'm not asking about old UILocalNotification. @alexburtnik

Comment: are you using swift or objective c.

Comment: It does not matter. @balkaransingh I want to know if it's possible. We could set it before iOS 10.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger Or https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger/1649772-init

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for answer first, But that can't be answer for my question. How to notify user every 30second after 1 hour later?

Comment: In http://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/ the author says "This is an interesting change from the older notification framework which had a fire date and repeat interval. The date components are more flexible but there is no easy way to fully replicate the fireDate property of the older framework. For example, if I want a daily trigger that starts in 1 week. I will look at some workarounds in a future post." But that post has not been written yet, and this question has no answer. Frustrating!